# Sharing Memory between application and driver

Tags: c++, windows, driver

I am having source code of DMA Driver and i developed an app to send data packets to this driver.

Problem is kernel crash always exist propably due to wrong pointer "Memory address" shared to driver.

Question is : How do i send a pointer to the driver and make to driver see my memory as the application see it.

I knew it may be mapping virtual memory to physical memory but i still am not sure of exact problem or how to solve !

hint :The driver is a system file and Info file so i can't debug in it.

My platform is `Windows 7` , here is what i try in code **in my app**:

```
DeviceIoControl(hDMADevice, IOCode, &TC, sizeof(TestCmd), NULL, 0, &bytes, &os))
```

where TC is structure having my address.

In the **DMADevice** , windows framework will call a function "EvtIoControl" which will take this address and reads its data.

```
Mydata = TC.mydata;
```

Comment: Without any code and the operating system you are targeting, it will be difficult to help you.

Comment: i updated the post including code and other info

Comment: A single line of code isn't sufficient.

Comment: _"The driver is a system file and Info file so i can't debug in it." :_ use WinDBG to debug drivers: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/hardware/ff551063(v=vs.85).aspx  Develop on your main computer, host a VM on this computer for your test system, use demote debugging from main to VM.

Comment: Still not enough information? Are you running 32-bit/64-bit? What is the user process? Also DMA is generally asynchronous, so I hope you are taking a copy of the user mode memory.

Comment: 64bit app , driver is 32bit .

Comment: my question is related to making the driver see same meomory i am giving to it in my call

Answer (score 0):

> "64bit app , driver is 32bit"

this is can not be. can be visa versa - 32bit app and 64bit driver.

in this case need understand that structure layout different for 32 and 64 (because different PVOID size - 4 or 8 bytes)
this is explain why wrong pointer "Memory address"
you need use [`IoIs32bitProcess`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff549372(v=vs.85).aspx) function - and read [Extended Example: Using IoIs32bitProcess](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff545635(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: NO , I don't think that will help , i think this has to be related to virtual addresses mapping into our real physical memory .

Comment: @mohamedrauof - you not give enough information about crash - where (on what code) this exactly happens. and your question was - "How do i send a pointer to the driver and make to driver see my memory as the application see it"

Comment: ok , i will rephrase the issue , after i run "with debugger" DeviceIOControl in driver code , the kernel blue screen is displayed . may be wrong address passed to kernel . another way of asking , how do i send data "array" to driver via DeviceIOControl ?

Comment: @mohamedrauof - you need open memory dump and look exactly on which command BSOD in driver. your info incomplete. again - you have 64bit driver and 32 bit app ? yes or no. you fix 32 bit data structs to 64 bit layout ? you mapping virtual to physical in driver ? say by `MmGetPhysicalAddress` or how ? "how do i send data "array" to driver via DeviceIOControl ?" but in what is problem here ?! by pointer. elementary